# gas estimate in loop

Tags: tokens, gas-estimate, testrpc-to-ropsten

I have two contract. I call function `placeBid` in other contract and i have warning gas estimation. help me. thanks. Can i call function which use gas  in loop through other contract? How i can get around this warning(gas estimate)?

Auction contract:

```
function placeBid(uint amount)  public notOwner returns(bool) {
    require(auctionState == State.Running);
    require(count>=amount);          
    trc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), startPrice);
    return true;
}
```

other contract:

```
function placeBidBox(address[] memory _addresses, uint[] memory _amounts)public{


   for(uint i=0; i<_addresses.length; i++){
       a = Auction(address(_addresses[i]));
       a.placeBid(_amounts[i]);
   }

}
```

update:
i resolved this problem with address of sender. i need send address of sender in arguments of function such as i call other contract and contract dont know sender.

Comment: Is your error "gas estimation failed"? It's not an error, it's a warning. The system has no way of estimating gas usage due to the calls to another contract. But yes, you can call external contracts in a a loop

Comment: thanks for fast answer, How i can get around this warning?

Comment: Added an answer. So you can probably just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The error about `gas estimation failed` is not actually an error but a warning. It means exactly what it says: the system is unable to estimate the required gas amount.

This is mostly due to the calls to external contracts. There is no way to know what functionality happens inside the external contracts and therefore there is no way to estimate the required gas usage.

You can pretty safely just ignore this warning if you know how much gas (`gas limit`) you are supposed to provide. If unsure just provide a big amount, for example 5 million - you will get the unused gas back.

So there is no problem per se in calling external contracts in a loop. The estimation would fail even if you performed the same call only once. Furthermore only having a loop without external calls will also result in the same problem as the system can't know for certain how many loops it has to execute.

Comment: thanks,  i have `gas required exceeds allowance (8000029) or always failing transaction` error after just ignore

Comment: oh well then the transaction probably requires more gas than is possible to give.

Comment: @malysh: OR (continuing the comment above)... the transaction is `always failing`. In fact, with the error that you've specified, this is mostly the case (I'd say - 1% of such errors are due to gas, and the other 99% are due to `always failing`). In your case, the `always failing` is probably the result of one of the `require` statements in your code. Another option, though less likely, is that for some value of `i`, the value of `_addresses[i]` is not an address of a properly deployed `Auction` contract.

Comment: Lastly, it could fail as a result of a `require` statement in your `trc20.transferFrom` function, whose code you haven't provided in your question. I would take the liberty to guess that `trc20.approve` should be called prior to calling that funcction.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for answer, if i call function `placeBid` singly, function is work. But if i call through loop , i have warning. i think that if problem was in `require` then why i dont have warning when i call function singly? thanks, where i wrong?

Comment: @malysh: So you do something like `Auction(address(_addresses[0])).placeBid(_amounts[0]);`,
 then `Auction(address(_addresses[1])).placeBid(_amounts[1]);`,
 then `Auction(address(_addresses[2])).placeBid(_amounts[2]);`,
 then `Auction(address(_addresses[3])).placeBid(_amounts[3]);`, ..., and it runs without reverting? If yes, then you're not wrong - the problem is indeed in the loop, hence indeed in the amount of gas that you provide when you execute the transaction (just as Lauri Peltonen has speculated).

Comment: Unless, of course, `_addresses[x]` is not the address of a properly deployed `Auction` contract.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for answer

Comment: @malysh: Well... is that indeed the case for you?

Comment: i dont know yet. I work. i will write  when i found

Comment: when i  call singly `placeBid` i call from  `Auction`  contract. I dont try  call `placeBid` from other contract

Comment: @goodvibration i have a question. May be  the warning (gas estimate) from that i use ropsten -test service? thanks